# How to render xml content in a HTML table using CGI Perl

Tags: html, xml, perl, cgi

I am trying to display an XML content (which is a SOAP request) in a simple HTML table using CGI Perl. However, the XML content is getting truncated inside 
the table cell. Can anybody suggest a solution to render the XML properly in
the HTML page?

Below is the code :

```
use strict;

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $qry = new CGI;

&show_html();


sub show_html {
    $qry->header();
    $qry->start_html(-bgcolor=>'#FFFFFF', -title=>'Rendering XML');
    my $body = &display_page();
    print $body;

    $qry->end_html;
}

sub display_page {

    my $html = qq{
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th> Key </th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> SOAP </td>
            <td>POST /Quotation HTTP/1.0 Host: www.demohost Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Content-Length: nnn  <?xml version="1.0"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.demourl1/2001/12/soap-envelope" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://www.demourl2/2001/12/soap-encoding" >     <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:m="http://www.demourl3/quotations" >              <m:GetQuotation>          <m:QuotationsName>MiscroSoft</m:QuotationsName>       </m:GetQuotation>                  </SOAP-ENV:Body>      </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    };
    return $html;

}
```

Comment: Please don't use an ampersand `&` when calling Perl subroutines. That hasn't been correct since Perl v5.5 was released seventeen years ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is full of characters like `<` and `&` which has special meaning in HTML.

You need to encode them.

That is typically done using [the `HTML::Entities` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities).

```
use HTML::Entities;
my $html_encoded_string = encode_entities($raw_xml_string);
```

---

Alternatively, use a template language which supports HTML filtering.

In Template-Toolkit, for instance, you would do something along the lines of:

```
<td>[% raw_xml_string | html %]</td>
```

---

You could also use CGI.pm's HTML generating functions (as you are doing in `show_html` but they are marked [HTML Generation functions should no longer be used](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used) so you really should *stop* using them in `show_html`.

The CGI.pm documentation recommends the Template approach.

Comment: This is partially working, still few characters are spilling out of that <td></td> element here and there.